# prep_call_sampler not found in Stan program in Linux using R

Tags: linux, stan, rstan

I have a simple .stan program for multilevel model that was running fine in Windows. But I was getting this strange error in Linux when I was running it.

'prep_call_sampler not found'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to find the source of the problem, updated packages and looked up online for solutions. Finally, I saw a blog with a post describing a similar problem in the [STAN forum](http://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/problems-compiling-in-ubuntu-machine/1944)

The solution was to simply replace the a*b with a * b in the .stan program and the model works fine in linux. Just thought of sharing this in case others face a similar problem when running stan program in linux using R.