# Calling Compiled rstan Model to Shiny App

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, stan, rstan, shinyapps

I have a Shiny app that works perfectly fine from my PC, but when I export it to Shinyapps.io, the pre-compiled rstan object (product of `stan_model()`) throws an error. Specifically the error I get looking back at the log is this:

`159: object@mk_cppmodule
Warning: Error in prep_call_sampler: could not find function "prep_call_sampler"`

Checking the compiled stan object, there is a function called mk_cppmodule. It has "formals", "body", and "environment" subheadings. It seems that the function `prep_call_sampler` is defined in "body" and takes the argument "object." It also seems that this "object" argument is supposed to be in the "formals" section; however, its value is listed as "missing" there.

Like I said, the model runs perfectly fine from my PC, and it has been successfully moved over to Shinyapps.io; however, it throws the error anytime the model is called, which makes me think that it's something to do with the server side not accessing the compiled C++. The model needs to be run by `sampling()` for the app to work. Has anyone had success getting a pre-compiled rstan model object to run on the Shinyapps.io?

Comment: Now, I  have  the same issue about `pre_call_sampler`.

Comment: Do you try to change `a*b` to`a * b`  according to the following page ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419614/prep-call-sampler-not-found-in-stan-program-in-linux-using-r

Comment: I have tried the added space between operations, but this does not work. Looking more closely at the log from shinyapps.io, the following information is given after the error:

`Error in prep_call_sampler: the compiled object from C++ code for this model is invalid, possible reasons:
   - compiled with save_dso=FALSE;
   - compiled on a different platform;
   - does not exist (created from reading csv files)`

I know that `save_dso` is not set to FALSE as I have tested it both ways with the current attempt specifying TRUE. I don't know which of the latter two options it could be, though

Comment: A compiled Stan model is generally only usable on the computer where it was compiled. You may have to recompile it on shinyapps.io or something.

Comment: After digging around in the stan forums, I was thinking that was the case since I couldn't find any way of pulling out the compiled code and hosting it on the server side. I've tried making the server compile the code, but it runs out of memory. I also tried generating a dummy `stan()` fit and leaving it in the R environment to avoid recompiling, but this doesn't seem to work either